# redirect user to download android app from browser

Tags: android, redirect, browser, google-play

Does anyone know how to redirect a user when they click on a link in a browser so that it will automatically open up google play store and ask the user to download a specific app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular old link to google play will redirect to the play app.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

But if you linking only for devices from an app it is best to use the following format.
market://details?id=

It might also be advantageous to set up a QR code, might be much easier for some users;

You can achieve this using googles chart api

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=market://details?id=packagename

Comment: that works!. Would you happen to know the equivalent for the apple store?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barefoot-world-atlas/id<9 digit app id>?mt=8   itunes on the phone also has an request url schema to snatch these and redirect to the app

Answer (score 0):

This will happen automatically, the user will be prompted if he wants to open the link with his browser of choice or the play store.